# Finding relationships among words in text

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, data-mining, semantics

In text, sometimes words tend to point to the same object.
For example: `John is an actor, his father Abraham was Doctor`

So here `his` points to `John`, and if we have the question `Who is John's father?` or `What is John's father's occupation?`, we should be able to answer this but I don't know how to achieve this.

Using lexical analysis, parse; using sentence parsing we can get `VP, NP, N` etc from the sentence. This can help for it - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylinkgrammar

Latent semantic analysis and [Probabilistic latent semantic analysis (PLSA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis) provides relation and can be used to analyze two-mode and co-occurrence data. But its not clear how it can be used.

More of kinda semantic and syntactic analysis.
Any suggestion or reference for this would much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe nltk can help you on that? http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

Comment: @danielfranca: thanks dear. it helps for syntactic analysis. Any clue for semantic analysis? does nltk has any support for this?

Comment: Yes, there's a chapter only for that :) http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @danielfranca: thanks, it is helping me to move forward. But I am confused.

Comment: I can use python nltk or prolog. Watson people uses prolog, as it is AI tool I guess it would be better choice. But could not decide which one to be followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is called *coreference resolution* as for the former problem (what does *his* refers to? John!) and *relation extraction* as for the latter (that is, `job(John, actor)`, `job(Abraham,doctor)`, and `father(John,Abraham)`).

There are tons of studies on these subjects. Hopefully, ACL Anthology is here to help :

- [coreference resolution](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=011664571474657673452%3A4w9swzkcxiy&cof=FORID%3A0&q=coreference#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=coreference&gsc.page=1)
- [relation extraction](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=011664571474657673452%3A4w9swzkcxiy&cof=FORID%3A0&q=relation%20extraction#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=relation%20extraction&gsc.page=1)

Answer (score 1):

There's a specific library NLTK-dependent that I think fits perfect for your case: https://code.google.com/p/nltk-drt/

This PDF explain very detailed how it works: https://code.google.com/p/nltk-drt/downloads/detail?name=NLTK-DRT.pdf

Comment: any idea about how such long query can be broken separate